# In-app billing or licensing?

Tags: android, android-billing

I find much similarity between  [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) and [licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html). As I understand, both use the Google Play app to query whether a certain product has been purchased.

Also, the developer console states:

> Licensing allows you to prevent unauthorized distribution of your app. It can also be used to verify in-app billing purchases.

How do the two relate? What are the main differences between them? In which cases one is preferable to another?

Comment: Edited the question to be more objective and less opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

The play licensing is to ensure that the user has bought a license on the play store.
As you know, this license is permanent, it doesn't support subscriptions.

From the page you linked:

> The Google Play Licensing service is primarily intended for paid applications that wish to verify that the current user did in fact pay for the application on Google Play.

On the other, in-app billing is there to sell somethings, from within your own app. The interface is different. It also supports subscriptions. From the page you linked:

> You can use In-app Billing to sell products as
>
> - Standard in-app products (one-time billing), or
> - Subscriptions, (recurring, automated billing)

Comment: Ok, so subscription is one thing. Is there anything else that is fundamentally different between the two?

Comment: In app billing gives better user experience since users don't need to install separate apps.

Comment: what is difference between recurring and automated billing of subscriptions?

Comment: I thought you cannot use any billing service without licensing the docs are sooo confusing